How to add "double footer" in Wordpress block editor?
How can I add two footers on-top of one another in Wordpress?
I'm trying to use the block editor to change the footer of my wordpress website. What I want is to have two footers that take-up the full width of the page, such that:

The "top" footer should have a light-grey background
The "bottom" footer should have a dark-grey background
There should be no margin between the two footers (the background colors should butt-up against each other with 0 pixels between these colors)
Obviously, the content of the footers should both be different









Screenshot of the siteorigin-corp theme demo site showing two footers with distinct content and background colors



I tried to add two "Footer" blocks on-top of each other. But, then, when I change the "design" of one footer, it changes the design of the other! Why would I want both footer blocks to be identical? That doesn't make sense.

ⓘ Note: this is a free site hosted on wordpress.com, so editing the theme (html, css, js, or php files) is not an option. Installing a plugin is not an option. Only normal editing in the default block editor is possible.

How can I add two footer blocks with distinct content in wordpress?

Sounds like you need to contact wordpress.com support. This WP Stack Exchange site can only help with wordpress.org installs.

@WebElaine This question is hosting provider agnostic. wordpress dot com runs wordpress dot org software. This problem is identical to a wordpress dot org install for non-technical users who are not able to edit html/css/js/php files.

with a classic wordpress install, we would advice to create a child theme.

@MichaelAltfield please review this page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Wordpress.com is a commercial enterprise and nobody here is interested in contributing free labour to their business.

As stated, this question is definitely on-topic. The hosting provider isn't at all relevant to the question; it was just added for context. Please re-open this question

This can be achieved by adding two "group" blocks inside of the "Footer" block.
You can then edit the "styles" of each group block to give them distinct background colors.
Finally, to remove the space between the two groups, you need to change the Margin top of the lower group block to None. You may need to slide it from None up to something, and then slide it back down to None to make this gap go away.
